# Exclude elements from overpass query

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have a query in overpass turbo, which searches for all buildings in the current bounding box (http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Dgv). I would like to **exclude buildings with certain id's from the output** - e.g. the house no. 14 in the center with OSM id=93778916.

Any ideas how to do that?

After reading some other posts I understand, that the Overpass QL "if:" statement might work. But I really have to clue how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, I would use the difference statement and simply substract buildings with a given id. The following example excludes way ids 93778916 and 209000787.

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(way[building=yes]({{bbox}}); 
 -
 way(id:93778916, 209000787);
);     
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, mmd! So easy and straight forward!

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind: Imagine I don't wannt to exclude elements by id but by OSM tag (e.g. wikidata=""). Is that also possible? Tried many different variants but none seems to work: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/DhN

Comment: You don't need any difference statement in this case, just use the exlamation mark to negate the search: `relation["admin_level"][!"wikidata"]({{bbox}}); out geom;`

Comment: But only certain Wikidata id's should be excluded.
So I would like to search for all relations which have the admin level and wikidata tag. But some of the elements with a certain wikidata value I want to exclude from the result.

Comment: Please open up a new question, this discussion has nothing to do with the original topic.